# How does a URL with both UTM and gclid look like?

Tags: html, url, utm

I'm trying to generate a URL that include both parameters but I don't know the order and a format.
Which has to come first?
What characters to be used to append them?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these properties are just query parameters of a URL, no explicit ordering is needed. Query params are declared using `=` and joined together using `&`. The entire query string starts with `?`. For example, you might do something like:

```
https://analytics.example.com/track?utm_source=twitter&gclid=XXXXXX
```

You can find some more information about Query Parameters on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) or by searching Google.